# RabbitMQ exception case data

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am new at RabbitMQ and doing first application. But I am confused a bit about exception stuations. For example I get a message from Queue. And an error occured while saving data to database. The data wil be lose. What is the solution of this problem?

```
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "10.1.2.34" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "business.orders", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                var data = channel.BasicGet(queue: "business.orders", noAck: true);

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data.Body))
                {
                    var order = (PlaceOrder)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);

                    // Throw exception. ????
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the manual `ack`:

```
var data = channel.BasicGet(queue: "business.orders", noAck: false);
```

insert into DB, if you don't have errors:

```
channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);
```

Please read here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html

```
bool noAck = false;
BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queueName, noAck);
if (result == null) {
    // No message available at this time.
} else {
    IBasicProperties props = result.BasicProperties;
    byte[] body = result.Body;
    ...
Since noAck = false above, you must also call IModel.BasicAck to acknowledge that you have successfully received and processed the message:
    ...
    // acknowledge receipt of the message
    channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);
}
```

btw I suggest to read also: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html section:

**Retrieving Messages By Subscription ("push API")**

The `basicGet` is slower respect to the `EventingBasicConsumer`